Problems booting the Linux system with FSCK
I have a server that contains 2 disks working in RAID 1. It seems that one of the files has become corrupted. When I try to boot, I get Give root password for maintenance. When I enter root, I tried to recover it with the fsck command but I haven't had any luck:
# fsck
fsck from until-linux 2.23.2
e2fsck
/dev/mapper/rhel-root is mounted
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting

What is the solution?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It may help the experts if you include the name of distribution and version number you have installed.

A typical well put together distro should automatically fsck your root filesystem after an unclean shutdown.  This automatic fsck fixes most normal problems.
So assuming that failed, there's something much more serious wrong (and a failed raid would count for that).  Likely one or both of your disks is failing, and fsck might actually make this worse.
You should run smartctl -a (possibly from a live disk instead of booting the system disk) on each individual disk and determine if your disks are failing before proceeding.  If they are, you should immediately back up any data there, in order of most important first, because it could fail completely while you are trying to copy files off.
After you have backed up critical data, you have the choice of attempting repair or replacing one or both disks and rebuilding the system.
If the disks appear to be ok, maybe this is just bad filesystem corruption.  You can try remounting the disks read only and run fsck (possibly with the force option), or run fsck from the live disk you might have used in the previous step.  Alternately, some distos have a rescue mode which should include an option to run fsck on the root disk, but since you didn't mention which distro, I can't suggest how to activate that.
You didn't mention what kind of raid (software, hardware??) you are using, but most raids have an automatic rebuild process to repair damage.  It is unclear from your question if this failed or just never started or if the corruption escaped notice of the raid, in which case you might be able to trigger a rebuild.
